# How to get insights data for public posts in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am very new to the Facebook graph API trying to explore the API but I'm finding it very difficult to understand how to proceed and what things I need inorder to achieve my goals.

What my goal is that I need to create an application which can take the facebook posts, videos of different public posts stored which are stored in the database and find out the impression counts of those posts. Which I'll need to store later in database.

Many different user's public posts will be stored in the database. From those URLs I need to fetch their insights data, Impressions etc. I have created an app in the facebook developers. Gone through documentation and played a bit with the explorer tool.

But I'm still not sure what things I need to do in order to achieve this. How do I need to proceed. Can anyone help me here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are no insights for user posts. And for page posts, you need page admin access to access this info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And yes that makes sense that we can't use the insights data like page post's impression counts, views, etc unless we have the admin access. 

So can I do that if I make the user login into my app with a facebook login and can I then use their posts data?

and in the 'App Review Status' in my facebook developers dashboard, I see a bunch of items in the 'Approved Items' section - email, public_profile, user_friends which are approved by default.

So if I get more items approved like 'user_posts', 'read_insights' who's data can I access using that then? only mine?

Comment: In short what I mean to say is that. There's no way to access someone's page posts insights (impressions etc) unless making them login? What do I need to do for that? 

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Approved only means that you _can_ ask normal users for permissions; but you still _have to ask_ them. Asking users to grant permissions to your app is done via the login flow. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: I can access this post's data like this https://graph.facebook.com/5718732097_10154285024557098?access_token=access_token_goes_here

So if I need to access this posts views, impressions count etc. I'll have to make the admin of this page login into my app and give my app permission for that. Am I correct or I'm missing something?